# Android studio; add .title and .snippet info to ArrayList <LatLng>

Tags: android, android-activity, maps

So i want to show a variety of lat long positions to show on my Map as Markers, via an Arraylist, and show their Names + custom information (in this example i show only two positions):

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList <LatLng> arrayList=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
LatLng basketball = new LatLng(50.375199, 5.883950);
LatLng football = new LatLng(50.370330, 5.901570);
```

Add them:

```
    arrayList.add(basketball);
    arrayList.add(football);
```

And show them as Markers:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(arrayList.get(i)).title("Basketball Court").snippet("It's a sunny square"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arrayList.get(i))); }
```

While this works, the problem is obviously all my markers have the same title and .snippet information.

My question is: how do i add Information to every Position in my arrayList and show it on every Marker via .title and .snippet.

I'm really looking forward to some answers, can't seem to find any. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a way:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        }

    });
    LatLng basketb = new LatLng(52.275000, 4.28000);
    LatLng footb = new LatLng(52.575441, 4.514373);
    // etc. etc. etc.


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(basketb)
            .title("Basketball Court")
            .snippet("Its a sunny place."));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(footb)
            .title("Football Court")
            .snippet("It's a crowdy place."));
    // etc. etc. etc.

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(basketb));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(footb));
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to create you custom wrapper class. Something like

```
    class MyModel{
         LatLng latLng;
         String title;
         String snippet;
    }
```

Then use `ArrayList<MyModel> list` and populate title and snippet based on the position in list.

Comment: Thanks for answering first of all, can you please edit with some more extensive examples (of the ArrayList<MyModel> list and calling my for loop to add markers.
I've made the MyModel class as java file, but in my Mapsactivity i'm pretty lost, because im struggling with giving my LatLng's string values in a list and doing the for loop.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Instead of 

LatLng basketball = new LatLng(50.375199, 5.883950);
LatLng football = new LatLng(50.370330, 5.901570);

You should do something like

        MyModel basketball = new MyModel(50.375199, 5.883950, "title basket", "snippet basket");
        MyModel football = new MyModel(50.370330, 5.901570, "title football", "snippet football");

Then add it to the list same as before.

Comment: Bummer. 
When i'm trying it like this im getting the error: 
constructor MyModel in class MyModel cannot be applied to given types;
MyModel basketball = new MyModel(50.375199, 5.883950, "Basketball court", "Sunny square");

  required: no arguments
  found: double,double,String,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: So i get rid of the error. But now i have errors running my for loop:

`for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(list.get(i)).title(list.get(i)).snippet(list.get(i));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(list.get(i))); }`   
It seems that it requires lat long but found double, double..

Comment: I guess the constructor for MyModel class is not correct. It should accept LatLng, then snippet, then title. So the constructor would be: 

MyModel(LatLng latlng, String snippet, String title)